# Dual citizenship/passports, one of which is expiring

Tags: passports

My fiancé has both an American and an Australian passport. We are currently in the USA, planning to fly out next week, but his US passport expires in 2.5 months. He usually travels on his AUS passport (valid for 9 more years) and will be entering Europe on his AUS passport.

We plan to be back in the USA the second week of March.

Does anyone know if he will have an issue leaving the USA with his US passport expiring, even though he has his AUS passport?

Comment: The US doesn't have exit immigration, there is no problem leaving the country. Will the US passport expire BEFORE you return to the US ?

Comment: @Hilmar:  The US passport "expires in 2.5 months" and they're planning to be back in about one month, so that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

He won't have any problems.  He would have problems trying to get to the US with an expired US passport, but that's not the case given the trip you've described.

Comment: Can't US citizens enter the country with an expired US passport, or even with no US passport? It can take a long time to get through immigration, but it reportedly should be possible (especially if the individual has another valid passport and therefore is allowed to board a plane...)

Comment: @Johnnyjanko absolutely.  But a US citizen cannot board a flight to the US with an expired US passport, much less without a passport (I wrote "have problems getting to the US," not "be unable to enter the US"). A US citizen with a VWP-eligible second citizenship might be able to get around that, but could also encounter problems trying to do so. I didn't write the second paragraph of the answer; it was added by another user.  I have rolled back to the first version.

Comment: now I get it. I thought "would have problems" was an euphemism for "it won't be possible", because it's often used that way (but not in this case). :)